# `qemu-nbd` list phantom partitions

Tags: partition, qcow2, nbd

When I mount a qcow2, like `qemu-nbd --connect=/dev/nbd0 /path/image.qcow2`, `fdisk /dev/nbd0 -l` lists me partition non visible on `/dev/`. And when I `mount /dev/nbd0 /path` It only mount what should be the first partition. And `partx -a /dev/nbd0` gives `partx: /dev/nbd0: failed to read partition table`

How to manage the partitions, manipulate them individually?

---

Output of `fdisk` wanted:

```
Disk /dev/nbd0: 154.28 GiB, 165654993920 bytes, 323544910 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6c727443

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nbd0p1      1970237472 3672215697 1701978226 811.6G 75 PC/IX
/dev/nbd0p2      1929382413 3883035520 1953653108 931.6G 72 unknown
/dev/nbd0p3               0          0          0     0B  0 Empty
/dev/nbd0p4        27394442   27394879        438   219K  0 Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: Add the output of `fdisk` to your question (with edit, not as a comment).